# create related class hierarchies with generics in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, generics

I'm trying to write generic code in Kotlin, and it becomes very cumbersome and in the end doesn't compile

```
interface Edge<N:Any, E:Edge<N,E>> {
    val from: N
    val to: N
    fun copy(f: N = from, t: N = to): E
}

interface WeightedEdge<N:Any,E: WeightedEdge<N, E>> : Edge<N, E> {
    val weight: Int
}

open class WeightedEdgeImpl<N:Any>(
    override val from: N,
    override val to: N,
    override val weight: Int
) : WeightedEdge<N,WeightedEdgeImpl<N>> {
    override fun copy(f: N, t: N): WeightedEdgeImpl<N> {
        return WeightedEdgeImpl(f, t, weight)
    }
}

class StrEdge(from: String, to: String, weight: Int) : WeightedEdgeImpl<String>(from, to, weight) {
    override fun copy(f: String, t: String): StrEdge {
        return StrEdge(f, t, weight)
    }
}

interface Graph<N:Any, E: Edge<N,E>> {

}

class StrGraph : Graph<String, StrEdge> {

}
```

StrGraph gives me a compilation error:

> Type argument is not within its bounds: should be subtype of 'Edge<String, StrEdge>'

but I think StrEdge *is* a subtype of Edge<String, StrEdge>

and I couldn't make it compile whatever tricks I'd tried

Answer (score 2):

> but I think `StrEdge` is a subtype of `Edge<String, StrEdge>`.

No it is not. Work your way backwards here.

- `StrEdge` implements `WeightedEdgeImpl<String>`,
- which implements `WeightedEdge<String,WeightedEdgeImpl<String>>`,
- which implements `Edge<String, WeightedEdgeImpl<String>>`.

`Edge<String, WeightedEdgeImpl<String>>` is not a subtype of `Edge<String, StrEdge>` because `E` is not contravariant (no `in E`). `E` is used in an output position in `copy`, so cannot be contravariant.

Let's think about what would happen if it *is* a subtype.

```
// I should be able to do this:
val e: Edge<String, StrEdge> = WeightedEdgeImpl<String>("from", "to", 1)

// according to the signature of "copy", it should return me a "StrEdge"
val strEdge = e.copy()
```

What would `e.copy()` actually do? It would return a `WeightedEdgeImpl`, *not* a `StrEdge`!

Consider whether you actually *need* `StrEdge` to be a distinct type from `WeightedEdgeImpl<String>`. If you don't, and you just want `WeightedEdgeImpl` to have a shorter name, use a `typealias`:

```
typealias StrEdge = WeightedEdgeImpl<String>
```

That said, you *can* make `StrEdge` implement `Edge<String, StrEdge>`, by adding an extra type parameter to `WeightedEdgeImpl`. But then you would not know what to return in `copy` - essentially the same problem as above:

```
open class WeightedEdgeImpl<N: Any, E: WeightedEdgeImpl<N, E>>(
    override val from: N,
    override val to: N,
    override val weight: Int
) : WeightedEdge<N, E> {
    override fun copy(f: N, t: N): E {
        // what should you return here?
        // you don't know what E is
    }
}

class StrEdge(from: String, to: String, weight: Int) : WeightedEdgeImpl<String, StrEdge>(from, to, weight) {
    override fun copy(f: String, t: String): StrEdge {
        return StrEdge(f, t, weight)
    }
}
```

I would just remove `WeightedEdgeImpl`, and directly implement `WeightedEdge`:

```
class StrEdge(
    override val from: String, 
    override val to: String, 
    override val weight: Int
) : WeightedEdge<String, StrEdge> {
    override fun copy(f: String, t: String): StrEdge {
        return StrEdge(f, t, weight)
    }
}
```

If you absolutely need `WeightedEdgeImpl`, perhaps because it contains other implementations that you don't want to repeat, you need implementors to pass in how to create an `E`:

```
open class WeightedEdgeImpl<N:Any, E: WeightedEdgeImpl<N, E>>(
    override val from: N,
    override val to: N,
    override val weight: Int,
    val factory: (N, N) -> E
) : WeightedEdge<N, E> {
    override fun copy(f: N, t: N) = factory(from, to)
}

class StrEdge(from: String, to: String, weight: Int, val somethingElse: String)
    : WeightedEdgeImpl<String, StrEdge>(
        from,
        to,
        weight,
        { f, t -> StrEdge(f, t, weight, somethingElse) }
    )
```

Or you can make `WeightedEdgeImpl` abstract, and its `copy` abstract too, so that subclasses has to implement it themselves.

Comment: Indeed, my real use case is much more complicated. I also have GraphBuilder, GraphValidator, GraphWriter etc. I tried to simplify it as much as possible.
The factory will not work for me becasue actually StrEdge has more members that need to be copied.

What I did in the end is add "as E" after every call to copy(), but I don't like it.

Maybe I'll suggest a language change, if I can think of a reasonable one.

Comment: @ModdyFire I think the factory should still work even if you have more members to be copied. Unless not all of them are `val`s, you can just capture them all in the lambda. See the edit.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out [in Sweeper's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76746625/6395627), `StrEdge` is not a subtype of `Edge<String, StrEdge>`. But I would step back and reconsider whether you actually need the self-referencing type parameter for `Edge` in the first place. With what you have in the question, you could simply change the retrun type of the `copy` function by overriding it in `WeightedEdge`.

```kotlin
interface Edge<N> {
    val from: N
    val to: N

    fun copy(from: N = this.from, to: N = this.to): Edge<N>
}

interface WeightedEdge<N> : Edge<N> {
    val weight: Int

    // note the default arguments will still work for this function
    override fun copy(from: N, to: N): WeightedEdge<N>
}
```

Then you can make a `WeightedGraph` interface so you don't have to have the edge type as a type parameter of the `Graph` interface either.

```kotlin
interface Graph<N> {
    // added to show it can be overridden to change the edge type
    val edges: List<Edge<N>>
}

interface WeightedGraph<N> : Graph<N> {
    
    override val edges: List<WeightedEdge<N>>
}
```

Finally, I would avoid creating implementations for specific types. The entire reason for having the `N` here is so you can parameterize it with different types as needed. If you want a string graph, then have a `Graph<String>`, not a `StringGraph : Graph<String>`.

Consider `List<T>`. There isn't a `StringList`, an `IntegerList`, and so on. The different implementations of `List` are based not on their element type, but on the way the list works internally. For instance, if you want an array-backed list, there's the `ArrayList`<sup>1</sup> implementation; and if you want a node-based list, there's the `LinkedList`<sup>1</sup> implementation.

---

<sup>1. At least on the JVM/Android.</sup>